# Including single quote in data while inserting to database

Tags: database, string, oracle, insert

I have a string "I love McDonald's burgers. it's the best."

and I would like to insert it into a column breaking them into 15 character strings.

Hence I need the result as string inserted in 3 rows

```
I love McDonald
's burgers. it'
s the best.
```

But if I use ' ' to include the ', an extra ' is present in the string which will affect my calculation of 15 character breakage.

Is there any other way to include ' without having to use one more ' to escape it?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add an extra ' if you're breaking the string into a variable:

```
DECLARE
  mcdonald_string VARCHAR2(50) := 'I love McDonald''s burgers. it''s the best.';
BEGIN
  WHILE LENGTH(mcdonald_string) > 0 LOOP
    INSERT INTO your_table(your_field) VALUES (SUBSTR(mcdonald_string,1,15));
    mcdonald_string := SUBSTR(mcdonald_string,16);  
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Doubling the quotation marks within a complicated literal,
>   particularly one that represents a SQL statement, can be tricky. You
>   can also use the following notation to define your own delimiter
>   characters for the literal. You choose a character that is not present
>   in the string, and then do not need to escape other single quotation
>   marks inside the literal:

```
-- q'!...!' notation allows the of use single quotes
-- inside the literal
string_var := q'!I'm a string, you're a string.!';
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/fundamentals.htm#sthref339